# How to check wifi connection without using ping in linux?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router

Basically I want to check if the computer is connected to the wifi (router) using a command line command. Ping is usually used to check internet connection, but I only want to know if is connected to the router, not about internet connection. I am using wicd as a network manager.

Thank you

Comment: Ping your router then.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe iwconfig is faster, as the information will go on a loop (text status bar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to ping your router, something like `ping 192.168.1.1`.

Alternatively, you can run `ifconfig` and check if you have an IP address. You can also do this with `iwconfig` and look for an ESSID.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that [`Wavemon`](http://www.monolith81.de/wavemon.html) should work for you.

**Install:**

- *Ubuntu/Debian*:

  ```
  # apt-get install wavemon
  ```
- *Fedora/CentOS/Red Hat*:

  ```
  # yum install wavemon
  ```

Starting to use `# wavemon`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I was thinking to get the information as standard output, as I needed for an all text status bar.